# How to prevent QWidget resize if hidden, and process the same resize events after the widget is shown?

Tags: qt, resize, qwidget

I want to prevent/disable all resize events of a QWidget when hidden (not visible), and process the same resize events after the widget is visible/shown again.

Answer (score 0):

you can reimplement resizeEvent and ignore the QWidget::resizeEvent when the widget is not visible and save the QResizeEvent object in a temporary variable. after that, reimplement the showEvent and call the QWidget::resizeEvent with their stored QResizeEvent variable ,before or after the showEvent occur